# How to get rid of transparent pixels in cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

I'm trying to get rid of transparent pixels in cycles. In Eevee you can set pixel filter width to 0, and it will work. In Cycles you can't set it to 0, only to 0.01.

Here's what I'm talking about:
'Blackman-Harris', if that matters. But same thing was with 'Gaussian' and 'Box' pixel types. I've also tried to change 'Linear' to 'Closest' on image texture node. Still doesn't work.

1. Width = 1.5

[image]
[image]

2. Width = 0.01

[image]
[image]

Is there any way to fix this? I need a pixel perfect masks for objects.

Comment: Setting the *Pixel Filter* to *Box* should disable anti-aliasing. How are you generating the masks? Additionally, but not related to your problem, you may want to set *Dither* to zero otherwise subtle noise is added to the image to avoid banding.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Setting it to Box type do nothing. Every object on my scene use unique obj id. I render OpenEXR file for every object ID MASK, and then convert it to json

Comment: If you just want the masks, I think you could use eevee instead. It's a Straight vs Premultiplied case.

Comment: Just a guess, but if the border of the plant texture is semi-transparent then the ID pass will not include them. Only parts with full opacity are included in the object pass when using Cycles.

Comment: @LeoNas eevee doesnt support object id pass

Comment: @RobertGützkow it is semi-transparent, thanks for the tip